# Find number of integral solution of 1/x+1/y=1/Nfactorial

Tags: algorithm

This question is a practice problem on interviewstreet.com.

> Find number of integral solution of 1/x+1/y=1/N!  for a given N

For N=1  answer is 1.
I tried to solve this questions , but cant predict from where to start. I am not from math background.

I am looking for the approach , how should I proceed towards the solution.
Is there any direct formula for this?

Comment: Are you sure you did not want to ask this is math.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to solve it as a iterative problem. All the solutions of N-1 are also valid for N. The only uncovered solutions are where x and y are both not divisible by N, which should be easier to count.

Comment: In addition to your answer, if none of them divisible by `N` he could find them by integer factorization of N and checking possible ways. But if there is a solution which can not obtain from N-1 how should do this?

Comment: cant get the solution. If Value of N is much larger like 10000000  then how will we solve it.